# Install errors in InstallShield 2008 Premier Edition

Tags: installshield

I have a setup which has been created using **InstallScript MSI** project type. This problem is encountered by our client and he wants a quick solution.

Let's assume I have initiated the installation from a path like

```
C:\Setup_V_1.0.0931.1
```

Inside this folder I have Setup.exe through which I will install the product. After installation or after some days pass I will change the path to:

```
C:\New\Setup_V_1.0.0931.1
```

and this time I want to modify the setup. Actually we are supporting 3 features: Server, Client and Service.

This time I want only Client and not Server. So I will click on the Setup.exe or click on Uninstallation Icon in the Startup Menu which will lead to Maintenance Mode there you have an option to Modify, Repair or Remove. I choose Modify and select the feature, but as the installation progresses, this error message will pop up:

> Setup could not find a file on the specified path or Disk. Please check
>   that the proper disk is inserted or specify a new path. Unable to
>   locate file c:\New\Setup_V_1.0.0931.1\setup.msi

Then, another popup will be shown saying:

> Error: 1706. No Valid Source could be found for product. The Windows
>   Installer cannot continue.

The next error message is:

> Error: 1603. Fatal error during installation. Consult Windows Installer
>   Help (Msi.chm) or MSDN for more information.

But if I change the path to its original location, it works fine.

How can I solve this?

I event checked in this registry path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\{Product-Key}
```

This key contains a lot of information inside InstallProperties. There is a key called InstallSource and its value is `C:\Setup_V_1.0.3909.1\`. Even after changing this value installshiled is still showing errors.

I found the same registry information for Uninstallation Information:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{Product-Key}
```

Comment: Does any one faced this issue..???
Please help...

Answer (score 0):

In your properties change ReinstallMode (or maybe Reinstall I forget which) from omus to vomus

the v means cache your install, so it will put your .msi file in c:\windows\installer so it can be used later.

Answer (score 0):

When installing a MSI, Windows Installer saves the original MSI path in registry (the InstallSource entry you mentioned). When running the MSI in maintenance mode, Windows Installer will use this path to find the installation data (CAB files).

When you move the MSI, the path stored in registry is no longer valid, so Windows Installer cannot find the installation data.

A possible solution is to use "Add or Remove Programs" or "Programs and Features" in Control Panel to modify the installation. This way the cached MSI is used.